# EditText opens wrong keyboard on some devices when setting inputType programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

We are setting the inputType of an EditText programmatically to either support decimal or non-decimal numbers:

```
editText.inputType = if (isDecimal) InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL else InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
```

This works on most devices and opens the numeric keyboard either with or without the decimal separator. On some devices however it opens the alphanumeric keyboard instead, e.g. on a Moto G5 with 8.1.0 or Caterpillar S31 with Android 8.

How do we fix this, so that the numeric keyboard will always be opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is by any chance **Gboard Keyboard** used on these phones?

Then please go to the [PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=de&gl=US) and check for **Updates**!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Manifest file inside your required activity .

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

For examle -

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You can check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft) to check other values also .

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Currently this setting is set to           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" but we will try your suggestion later as soon as we hold one of the affected devices in our hands. Currently I do not fully understand how this change should affect HOW the keyboard is shown but only WHEN it is shown. Our keyboard is shown the right time but instead of a numeric keyboard, it shows the alphanumeric one.